# Trying to get an object value in from a key in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, vue.js

I'm trying to get a country label (name) from a value (country code) in an object.

In Vue.js I'm trying to build a computed property to return the name of the country based on the country code from an API request.

In the template:

```
countryLabel () {
    var countries = require('../../plugins/countries')
    var countryCode = this.content.country
    function getLabelByValue(countries, countryCode) {
        return Object.keys(countries).find(label => countries[value] === countryCode)
    }
}
```

From a list of countries:

```
module.exports = [
    { value: 'AF', label: 'Afghanistan' },
    { value: 'AX', label: 'Aland Islands' },
    { value: 'AL', label: 'Albania' },
    { value: 'DZ', label: 'Algeria' },
    { value: 'AS', label: 'American Samoa' },
    { value: 'AD', label: 'Andorra' },
    { value: 'AO', label: 'Angola' },
    { value: 'AI', label: 'Anguilla' },
    { value: 'AQ', label: 'Antarctica' },
    { value: 'AG', label: 'Antigua and Barbuda' },
    ...
]
```

Comment: So what's the problem ?

Comment: I'm not getting anything returned

Comment: Well, Object.keys on an array will return you `0->n`. I think what you want is simply `countries.find(country => country.value === countryCode)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't want to be calling `Object.keys` on an array.

Something like this is probably more what you want:

```
function getLabelByValue(countries, countryCode) {
    const entry = countries.find(item => item.value === countryCode);
    return entry ? entry.label : null;
}
```

The problem is that calling `Object.keys` on an array will return an array of numbers that have been converted to strings:

```
> console.log(Object.keys(['this', 'is', 'an', 'array']));
['0', '1', '2', '3']
```

Since your `exports` is already an array, you can call `find()` on it directly.

Comment: I had to remove the function wrapped around it, but it's worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A better way to do this would be to use an object, which is always the fastest way to lookup anything in javascript because objects are dictionaries. So if you changed your export to look like:

`{
    AF: 'Afghanistan',
    AX: 'Aland Islands',
    etc...
}`

then you'd be able to do instant lookups by doing `countries[countryCode]`.

Comment: Thanks. Out of curiosity, how would you do the look up?

Comment: See the last part of my post. It's just a regular object, so you'd do something like `countries['AF'], and you'd get the value of that key.

Comment: I see what you mean. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on rossipedia's answer this is working for me:

```
countryLabel () {
    const countries = require('../../plugins/countries')
    return countries.find(item => item.value === this.content.country).label
}
```

Comment: Just be careful about the `this` context. If you decide to change your arrow function into a standard function, this code will break.